# When I Branch from Trunk I need to create a new Virtual Directory. Anyway around this?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, branch, webserver

the Trunk of my app points to

```
<IISUrl>http:///localhost/MyApp/</IISUrl>
```

Whenever I create a new branch, I end up having to edit MyApp.csproj to change the target URL to

```
<IISUrl>http:///localhost/MyAppBranchName/</IISUrl>
```

Is there any way that I don't need to do this? The reason is the number of branches are starting to add up and there's a lot of virtual directories in IIS. I suppose I could use the ASP.NET Dev server, but as this solution is already configured to use IIS, I'd prefer to keep using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is delete the Virtual Directory for trunk - it is a manual task and a bit of a pain but it gets the job done and I don't have to worry about breaking my colleagues environments after I merge back to trunk. VS will prompt you to create an IIS VD when you open the branch solution.

So essentially you have a small manual task and only one Virtual Directory at a time.